# WPF Unhandled Exception - Looking for a better solution than DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf, unhandled-exception

I am using a 3rd party Chart control. The control can be configured in XAML to display the value of a data point when the mouse moves over it. If there is no data in the chart, it throws an exception. I can catch the exception in the Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException event. I would prefer to catch the exception in my user control which hosts the Chart control. I don't see a way to intercept the exception, because the chart control gets the mouse event directly.

My questions are:
Is there a better way to catch the exception? If not, is this a weakness in the WPF architecture?

Comment: You could try setting UIElement.IsHitTestVisible=false....then I think it won't get the mouse input....UIElement.HitTestCore might also be an option.

Comment: The control uses the mousemove event do display info, so IsHitTestVisible needs to be true. The bigger question is, is there a better way to catch exceptions like this?

Comment: Similar question here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106107/catching-an-unhandled-exception-prior-to-it-reaching-application-level.